# Trying to append content to numpy array

Tags: arrays, loops, numpy, tweepy, textblob

I have a script that searches Twitter for a certain term and then prints out a number of attributes for the returned results.

I'm trying to Just a blank array is returned. Any ideas why?

```
public_tweets = api.search("Trump")

tweets_array = np.empty((0,3))

for tweet in public_tweets:

    userid = api.get_user(tweet.user.id)
    username = userid.screen_name
    location = tweet.user.location
    tweetText = tweet.text
    analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
    polarity = analysis.sentiment.polarity

    np.append(tweets_array, [[username, location, tweetText]], axis=0)

print(tweets_array)
```

The behavior I am trying to achieve is something like..

```
array = []
array.append([item1, item2, item3])
array.append([item4,item5, item6])
```

`array` is now `[item1, item2, item3],[item4, item5, item6]`.

But in Numpy :)

Comment: Stick with the list append in the loop.  It's faster, and easier.

Answer (score 0):

`np.append` doesn't modify the array, you need to assign the result back:

```
tweets_array = np.append(tweets_array, [[username, location, tweetText]], axis=0)
```

Check `help(np.append)`:

> Note that
>       `append` does not occur in-place: a new array is allocated and
>       filled.

In the second example, you are calling list's `append` method which happens in place; This is different from `np.append`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the source code for `np.append`

```
In [178]: np.source(np.append)
In file: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    ....docs
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        .... special case, ravels
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

In your case `arr` is an array, starting with shape `(0,3)`.  `values` is a 3 element list.  The is just a call to `concatenate`.  So `append` call is just:

```
np.concateante([tweets_array, [[username, location, tweetText]]], axis=0)
```

But `concatenate` works with many items

```
alist = []
for ....:
   alist.append([[username, location, tweetText]])
arr = np.concatenate(alist, axis=0)
```

should work just as well; better because list append is quicker.  Or remove a level of nesting and let `np.array` stack them on a new axis, just as it does with `np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`:

```
alist = []
for ....:
   alist.append([username, location, tweetText])
arr = np.array(alist)   # or np.stack()
```

`np.append` has multiple problems.  Wrong name.  Doesn't act inplace.  Hides `concatenate`.  Flattens without much warning. Limits you to 2 inputs at a time. etc.